# The relation between conformally related metrics and conformal vector fields?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry, vector-fields

Two metrics $g_{1}$ and $g_{2}$ are conformally equivalent metrics if $g_{2}=e^{2\theta}g_{1}$
A vector field $X$ is called conformal if $L_{X}g=2\theta g$ where $L_{X}$ is the Lie derivative with respect to $X$.

Is there a relation between both concepts?

Comment: Yes, and you [answered this question elsewhere](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/614373/111742): the flow of a conformal vector field is a family of conformal maps. That is, pulling back $g $ under a flow map gives you a conformally equivalent metric.